# 7-Zip - How to output results to a different folder than the batch location?

Tags: batch-file

I use the following batch file which zips the contents of folders individually retaining the folder filename and, once completed, moves them to a different destination folder. This works but, for time and space reasons, I want the resulting zip files to be created in the destination folder as they are being zipped.

This is the batch I am currently using.

```
for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.zip" "%%X\"
move *.zip c:\Output
```

I've been experimenting but, so far, all I've accomplished is creating one file called (.zip), in the destination folder, that contains ALL the the separately zipped folders instead of generating separate zip files like the above command accomplishes. I have tried using the -o command in various places but have been unsuccessful. Any help or direction would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "C:\Output\" "%%X.zip" "%%X\"
```

Comment: Try to read 7zip docs?

Comment: As you said in the post yourself `-o` is used to set the output directory. How have you used it and what are the results? I think you just append the directory after the `-o` without a space.

Comment: @user202729 the `o` switch only works in combination with `x` or `e` when extracting files.

Comment: [Dupe on super user](https://superuser.com/q/963155). [Dupe on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/615874).

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the target dir at the same spot where you are defining the file name:

```
for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "C:\output\%%X.zip" "%%X\"
```

The `o` switch only works when extracting files (`x` - extract with full paths or `e` - extract):

```
7z x archive.zip -oc:\Doc
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am very rusty but it seems so obvious now that I see it. This works perfectly!

Comment: @futuremoves You're welcome. As your question is answered, please mark my answer as a solution to indicate other users that there is nothing left to do here.